# ICustomTypeDescriptor databinding to textbox

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I have a model that implements ICustomTypeDescriptor. This is because I want to be able to add custom properties ... that are not in the object and bind them to a textbox. The strange part is that the binding works great to a PropertyGrid but not to a textbox.

This code works:

```
DynamicClass<ExtensionModel> binder = new DynamicClass<ExtensionModel>(ext);
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = binder;
```

but not his one:

```
var binder = new DynamicClass<ExtensionModel>(ext);
_versionLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", binder, "SelectedVersion", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

In this case I get Object does not match target type. exception. If I put ext instead of binder in the binding it works fine.

Is there a problem with the textbox binding capabilities?

My code for DynamicClass is:

```
public class DynamicClass<T> : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private readonly T _object;

    public DynamicClass(T trackedObject) 
    {
        _object = trackedObject;
    }

    // Collection to code add dynamic properties
    public KeyedCollection<string, DynamicProperty> Properties { get; private set; }

    // ICustomTypeDescriptor implementation
    AttributeCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(_object, true);
    }

    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(_object, true);
    }

    string ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(_object, true);
    }

    TypeConverter ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(_object, true);
    }

    EventDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(_object, true);
    }

    PropertyDescriptor ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(_object, true);
    }

    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(_object, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(_object, true);
    }

    EventDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(_object, attributes, true);
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_object, true);
    }

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_object, attributes, true);
    }

    object ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return _object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see any of your custom descriptors? (in particular for SelectedVersion) In general this should work fine (I've done plenty of crazy custom descriptor stuff), so my gut say: bug in the code you aren't showing

Comment: also, you mention "textbox", but you seem to be binding to a ComboBox...?

Comment: I will add the code now. Sorry wrong copy/paste with the binding :(

Comment: Yeah, GetPropertyOwner is badly supported in many places; I strongly suspect you're going to have to daisy-chain the descriptors

Comment: the problem is that GetPropertyOwner is never called :( That's why I suspect there is a label issue.

Comment: exactly, so combo-box is passing the wrong object to the descriptor. Hence the need to daisy chain with the wrapper handling the object indirection

Comment: can you give me a code example ... I don't understand how to daisy chain with the wrapper

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental issue here in that you are giving out a descriptor for the *actual* object (`ExtensionModel`), but the combo-box only knows about the wrapper (`DynamicClass<T>`), so will be trying to invoke methods on the wrong object. You can avoid this by wrapping the descriptors in something that swaps the object for you; such as:

```
class IndirectDescriptor : PropertyDescriptorDecorator
{
    private readonly object instance;
    public IndirectDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor tail, object instance) : base(tail)
    {
        this.instance = instance;
    }
    protected override object GetComponent(object component)
    {
        return instance;
    }
}

abstract class PropertyDescriptorDecorator : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private readonly PropertyDescriptor tail;
    static Attribute[] GetAttributes(AttributeCollection attribs)
    {
        var arr = new Attribute[attribs.Count];
        attribs.CopyTo(arr, 0);
        return arr;
    }
    public PropertyDescriptorDecorator(PropertyDescriptor tail) : base(tail.Name, GetAttributes(tail.Attributes))
    {
        this.tail = tail;
    }
    protected virtual object GetComponent(object component)
    {
        return component;
    }
    public override void AddValueChanged(object component, EventHandler handler)
    {
        tail.AddValueChanged(GetComponent(component), handler);
    }
    public override void RemoveValueChanged(object component, EventHandler handler)
    {
        tail.RemoveValueChanged(GetComponent(component), handler);
    }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return tail.CanResetValue(GetComponent(component));
    }
    public override TypeConverter Converter
    {
        get { return tail.Converter; }
    }
    public override string Category
    {
        get { return tail.Category; }
    }
    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get { return tail.ComponentType; }
    }
    public override string Description
    {
        get { return tail.Description; }
    }
    public override bool DesignTimeOnly
    {
        get { return tail.DesignTimeOnly; }
    }
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes
    {
        get { return tail.Attributes; }
    }
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get { return tail.DisplayName; }
    }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetChildProperties(object instance, Attribute[] filter)
    {
        return tail.GetChildProperties(GetComponent(instance), filter);
    }
    public override object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return tail.GetEditor(editorBaseType);
    }
    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return tail.GetValue(GetComponent(component));
    }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        tail.SetValue(GetComponent(component), value);
    }
    public override bool IsBrowsable
    {
        get { return tail.IsBrowsable; }
    }
    public override bool IsLocalizable
    {
        get { return tail.IsLocalizable; }
    }
    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return tail.IsReadOnly; }
    }
    public override string Name
    {
        get { return tail.Name; }
    }
    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get { return tail.PropertyType; }
    }
    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        tail.ResetValue(GetComponent(component));
    }
    public override bool SupportsChangeEvents
    {
        get { return tail.SupportsChangeEvents; }
    }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return tail.ShouldSerializeValue(GetComponent(component));
    }
}
```